# In matlab, how can we change the value of variables in steps?

Tags: matlab, variables, simulink

For example, I have a code in which I have 3 variables Q,Q1,Q2 each having some numerical value.
Then some formulae with Q and Q1 to calculate some things. r is one of the things calculated here.
Now if r<1 I want Q to take the value of Q1 and Q1 to take the value of Q2 in the above formulae. Or simply I want the formulae to change Q to Q1 and Q1 to Q2. Its like a progression which I want it to follow. Is there some loop for this? Or something with which this can be done? Like creating some different function scripts? Or some Simulink function which can be used for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 if r<1

   [Q1,Q2]=deal(Q,Q1);

 end
```

Comment: Hi thanks. One more thing, after it switches the values, I want to discontinue the further calculations and start again from top?